# Unsure why this for/if code returns the wrong Boolean variable

Tags: python

Can anyone explain why this returns `False`?

```py
def letter_check(word, letter):
  for let in word:
    if let == letter:
      return True
    else:
      return False

print(letter_check("strawberry", "a"))
```

I'm learning in an online programme and it lets you view the solution code, but no other explanation is given. I can see why their code works (return `False` is not linked by an else statement and it's at the same indent level as the for loop). However, I can't see why mine doesn't.

Comment: Your code looks at the first letter of the word only, and returns either True or False - none of the other letters matter at all, and you might as well not have that `for` loop.

Comment: It's unclear why you expected `True`, we don't know what specification led you to write this program. Don't just run the code online, use a basic debugger (e.g. https://pythontutor.com/ if you don't have an IDE locally) so you can see what _actually_ happens.

Comment: When your function is run, the `let` variable is assigned to `'s'` (the first letter of `strawberry`) and then the `if` checks this against `'a'` (the other parameter you supplied) and finds they are not equal, so it takes the `else:` branch and returns `False`.

Comment: A `return` statement will immediately stop the function. This is useful when you've found the letter you want; there's no need to go looking at more letters. However, you don't want to do that when the letter hasn't been found because it might occur later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `return` statement exits the function immediately. In your case, the function you wrote would "translate" to English like this.

1. Get the first letter of the word.
2. Does the first letter matches the letter we want to look for? If it does, exit the function and return `True`.
3. Does the letter not match the letter we want? If not, then return `False`.

In your case, your function will always exit after checking the first letter. What I assume you want to do is return `False` if the letter you are searching for is *nowhere* in the word. To do so, the English would look like this:

1. Get the first letter of the word.
2. Does the first letter match what we are searching for? If it does, exit the function and return `True`.
3. Does the letter not match? Then get the next letter of the word and keep checking.
4. Are you all out of letters to check? That is, have you checked every letter in the word? *Then*, return `False`.

The correct code would look like this:

```py
def check_letter_in_word(my_word, my_letter):
    for letter in my_word:
        if letter == my_letter:
            return True
    return False
```

Notice the indentation of the `return False`. That line gets executed *after* we search through the entire word.

Answer (score 0):

```
def letter_check(word, letter):
  for let in word:
    if let == letter:
      return True
  else:
      return False

print(letter_check("strawberry", "a"))
```

output:-

```
True
```

just fix the `else` indentation. so. it will iterate through all the letters in the string and when the condition is not met,then it will execute the else statement .